# Missing values on count in mysql

Tags: mysql, count, gaps-and-islands, week-number

I'm just stuck with this issue atm and I'm not 100% sure how to deal with it.

I have a table where I'm aggregating data on week

```
 select week(create_date),count(*) 
from user 
where create_date > '2015-02-01'
and id_customer between 9 and 17
group by week(create_date);
```

the results that I'm getting have missing values in the count, as shown below

```
5   334
6   376
7   394
8   405
9   504
10  569
11  709
12  679
13  802
14  936
15  1081
16  559
21  1
24  9
25  22
26  1
32  3
34  1
35  1
```

For example here from 16 to 21 there a obviously 4 values missing I would like these values to be included and count to be 0. I want this because I want the weeks to be matching with other metrics as we are outputting them in an excel file for internal analysis.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that an sql query cannot really produce data that is not there at all.

You have 3 options:

1. If you have data for each week in your entire table for the period you are querying, then you can use a self join to get the missing weeks:

   `select week(t1.create_date), count(t2.id_customer)
   from customer t1
   left join customer t2 on t1.id_customer=t2.id_customer and t1.create_date=t2.create_date and t2.id_customer between 9 and 17
   where t1.create_date > '2015-02-01'
   group by week(t1.create_date)`
2. If you have missing weeks from the customer table as whole, then create a helper table that contain week numbers from 1 or 0 (depending on mysql config) to 53 and do a left join to this helper table.
3. Use a stored procedure that loops through the results of your original query and inserts the missing data in the resultset using a temporary table and then returns the extended dataset as result.

Comment: That was a very thorough explanation pretty straight forward from here I think, since there are values missing I'll go ahead and create that helper table u suggested and it should be taking a direction then. Thank you again, much appreciated.

Comment: Guys if the first day is missing, i.e the first week happens to be 5, what's the best solution so that it starts from the first week?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The first day is missing from where? Where do you want to start: week 1 or 5?

Comment: Sorry, I'll clarify my question. I want select statement to return from the first week onward, but some datasets don't have records for the primary number of weeks. i.e select statement returns record 5 onward. When I use ur query the return values I get don't start from 1 but rather 5. I hope that's clear enough. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Then add a where criteria filtering those records out.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is no data matching your criteria for the missing weeks. A solution will be to join from a table that has all week numbers. For example if you create a table weeknumbers with one field weeknumber containing all the numbers from 0 to 53 you can use something like this

```
select weeknumber,count(user.*) 
from weeknumbers left join user on (weeknumbers.weeknumber=week(user.create_date) 
and user.create_date > '2015-02-01'
and user.id_customer between 9 and 17)
group by weeknumber;
```

Additionaly you might want to limit the week numbers you do not want to see.
The other way is to do it in the application.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was kinda considering that option through the desk research, but I've a better direction now. #thumbsup